# Easiest Way to Parse data from twitter with Cocoa

Tags: xml, cocoa-touch, parsing, nsxmlparser

I've followed the tutorial from here: [Twitter Client Tutorial](http://brandontreb.com/objective-c-programming-tutorial-creating-a-twitter-client-part-1/) to make a little twitter app. Now I need to find out how to parse the XML twitter gives you when you make a request. I've looked at tons of tutorials on phrasing xml on the iPhone but none have made much sense because Im still new to cocoa. Twitter stores the text of the tweet in something like this `<text> Some tweet here </text>`. From reading the tutorials I think this would involve `nsxmlparser` but I'm not sure. If anyone could share some code that could parse the `<text> Some tweet here </text>` things into an array that would be really great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try the [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) API ? It is a complete integration of Twitter API in Objective-C. It may save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

And if you really want to build you own engine, maybe it's an idea to look at the JSON version of the twitter API. JSON can be easily parsed using, for example, [this library](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/downloads/list).